# How to investigate "Exception form Deps recompute" what are the clues?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am on a big project, first exposure to Meteor, and I am starting to get this very often.  It will be hard to trace it back to a particular commit, as it seemed intermittent.

What is a fruitful way to approach finding the problem?  Is there anything in the exception that helps narrow it down?  How do I step through/set breakpoints in/rule out the Deps?
All my deps are the auto ones from mongo operations, or one on a session var, nothing explicit.

Thank you

https://gist.github.com/jimmack1963/6254452

Comment: Were you able to track this down? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Not so far.  I kind of restarted from the beginning, and haven't triggered this problem yet.

Comment: So far, I've been able to determine the following reasons for this error to occur: (1) calling a method on an object that isn't an object/trying to access an object that isn't an object. (2) Trying to Array.sort(fn) an array that isn't an array (no type checking). The errors tend happen during rendering or as a result of an event that triggers a render, at least, so far in my project. Hope this helps! No real answer yet...

Comment: Thanks.  You are probably right about an error existing.  I just would like to tie the deps error to what it thinks it is associated with.  Name of template?  Name of collection?  Source code line?  Seems observatory is moving in that direction with their service.  Will need to take a better look.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, this usually means you have crashing code within a template. You're using `{{#each` on something that's not an array or object, or some other no-no. If you were actually using `Deps.autorun` somewhere, presumably you would see your function in the stack trace; but if the trace is just a list of core Meteor functions, that means the problem is likely in a template or one of its helpers.

Comment: Thanks.  That project was a first draft anyway, and I don't seem to git this any more with my new dev, so probably a beginners mistake.  I think observatory is starting to give some good feedback into internals, while on the subject.

Comment: In my case, I was creating a document, but not using a callback to then findOne() by the id. When I resolved that and a few other of my own errors, problems went away.

Answer (score 2):

This was pretty helpful to anyone else getting this.

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/TypeError_-_Cannot_read_property_nodeName_of_null