# Exception from Deps afterFlush function: undefined debug.js:43

Tags: meteor

I'm getting this error on the client side

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: undefined debug.js:43
```

But it doesn't seem to be very specific about the error.

Has anyone else seen it?

Comment: What's in debug.js around line 43? Is that your file?

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin?

Comment: debug.js is part of the Meteor library.  I am using several jQuery plugins

Comment: debug.js is basically just a console.log wrapper which avoids issues with console.log in Internet Explorer. If you have not figured out the cause of the problem you will like have to use the browsers debugger and trace back through the call stack to figure out what is actually causing the problem.

Comment: The answer is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283607/how-to-investigate-exception-form-deps-recompute-what-are-the-clues)!

Comment: In the meantime Deps has been replaced by [`Tracker`](https://www.meteor.com/tracker).